# How to link the variable for the function to the button's variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Im new to javascript, is there any way to link my function's var to the button so that the function can be executed properly.I cant seem to link the function's variable to the button's id or even the button itself.

```
//My button
 var btn1 = document.createElement('button');
 btn1.textContent = questions[0].A
 btn1.id = 'optionA'
 document.body.appendChild(btn1);
 btn1.addEventListener('click', fSubmit);   

//My Function
var score=0;
function fSubmit(){
var correctanswer=btn1;
if(correctanswer.checked==true){
score++;
alert("Answer is correct! "+"Your Score is now "+score++)}
else{
alert("Answer is incorrect!")}
}
```

Comment: `button` elements don't have a `checked` property, for a start.

Comment: So how do i do it? i really need to solve this issue, or maybe is there any way to link the var correctanswer to the button's id?

Comment: Also do you mean to increment your score twice? You're doing it once then again in the first alert.

Comment: i only meant to increment it once

Comment: i should put alert("Answer is correct! "+"Your Score is now "+score)} only right

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript and DOM tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

what I think you are trying to say is that you want to bind the "correctness" of a button's data to the score.  What I would do is [add a custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to each button containing 'true' or 'false' value for that button.

Like so:

```
btn1.dataset.correctOrNot = true
```

Then you test that *value* in your fSubmit function:

```
if (btn1.dataset.correctOrNot === true) {
  // etc. etc.
}
```